# What sort of neural network model do I need when the input varies along 1 dimension, the output varies across another, and the order doesn't matter?

Tags: neural-networks, lstm

I have a model where the input can be N rows if real numbers. N can vary over time. The order of the rows is not important.

The output needs to be a Nxm matrix, where m could vary, though I could keep it fixed if necessary.

I have read that LSTM networks are suitable for sequences of data, but what if the order of the rows does not matter?